# Conflict between two mikrotic's vpn access

Tags: mikrotik

The company I work has two physical addresses, and a mikrotic in each of the addresses with vpn configured and working, however if I am at address 1 and I connect to vpn at address 2 and I try to access or ping the server does not work, as if the server was out of the network or disconnected, however if I'm out of both networks, and I connect to vpn at address 2, I can connect and ping normal on the server.
What I believe is happening is, both mikrotics are at 192.168.2.1~254, and another address (my home for example) is at 192.168.1.1~254, maybe there is some conflict. If in my house I connect to both vpn at the same time, pinging/accessing the server at address 2 does not work, I further reinforce my theory that there may be a conflict between the two networks.
Is there any configuration that I can fix this?

Comment: Please, draw a network diagram, with addresses specified on each interface. It is hard to deduce your network structure from your description. You may mask public IPs, but don't change private ones (this is senseless).

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, which means you should move your Question to superuser OR contact the IT Department of your Company. We are no end user support :-)